# GNOME Network Displays Errors

Tags: 20.04, gnome, display, dbus

I get the following errors when run GNOME Network Displays. Any help troubleshooting would be appreciated. I am running a fresh install Ubuntu 20.04.

```
Gtk-Message: 18:20:32.421: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 18:20:32.422: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 18:20:33.036: Error calling DBus method during Screencast portal initialization: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.ScreenCast” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop
** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 18:20:33.036: Error initing screencast portal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.ScreenCast” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop
** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 18:20:33.036: Screencasting portal is unavailable! It is required to select the monitor to stream!
** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 18:20:33.036: Falling back to X11! You need to fix your setup to avoid issues (XDG Portals and/or mutter screencasting support)!
** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 18:20:53.666: Could not start P2P find: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.NotActive: WPA Supplicant management interface is currently unavailable.
```

Answer (score 2):

Package search says that [*org.freedesktop.portal.ScreenCast*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=org.freedesktop.portal.ScreenCast&searchon=contents) is contained in the `xdg-desktop-portal-dev` package.

You have to try installing it by

```
sudo apt-get install xdg-desktop-portal-dev
```

then reboot and check screencast functionality again.

Comment: Having the same issue, but I have those packages installed

Comment: Also having the same issue, does not resolve.