# Cast the entire desktop with Chromecast?

Tags: 21.10, chromecast

I'm talking from either Gnome Shell, or any other desktop environment. I can already cast from Chrome, but I'd like to cast the entire desktop + audio (if possible), without Chrome.

Comment: Casting the desktop is a choice in the Chrome/sources.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ubfan1 I've since tested in Chrome. It's possible to cast the desktop, I  realized, but not with audio. In any case, I was looking for a solution that works without Chrome, similarly to this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2977/cast-to-tv-desktop-stream-add-on/ (which appears unmaintained, along with the extension it depends on).

Comment: Does mkchromecast and mkchromecast-pulseaudio (or ...alsa) with necessary dependencies seem to be what you want?  Check the apt-cache show  descriptions.  Looks like there is some way your audio casting would work.

Comment: @ubfan1 I haven't tested it yet, largely because it only supports streaming video files (as far as I can tell, not the actual desktop), and if I'm not mistaken, not audio-only.

Comment: Make up your mind, do you want Chrome, as you say in title (`Is it possible to use Chrome`) or not  (as you say at the end: `if possible without Chrome`)??

Comment: @cipricus I will edit the title to make "Chromecast" one word, but I'm clearly referring to a technology, not a program.

Comment: Oh, now I see (there is no Chrome browser in title): chromecast without using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*UPDATED ANSWER:*

Testing in later Ubuntu (Kubuntu 23.10) [Mkchromecast](https://mkchromecast.com/) seems to work best for screen mirroring.
(I have used [this](https://linuxhint.com/stream_linux_to_tv/) solution, installing from Ubuntu repos, thus python is not used in the commands).

I am able to mirror the entire laptop screen (as said [here](https://github.com/muammar/mkchromecast/issues/104#issuecomment-327012403)) with something like:

```
mkchromecast --name <NAME-of-DEVICE> --control --notifications --video --resolution <YOUR_RESOLUTION> --screencast
```

(More parameters can be used, see `mkchromecast --help`.)

Setting the exact resolution is necessary. The available ones are:

```
- 480p.
- 720p.
- 1366x768.
- 1080p.
- 2k.
- 1440p.
- uhd.
- 2160p.
- 4k.
```

In this case you need to also use `pavucontrol` and send the audio stream:

[image]

There is a few seconds delay between the computer and the other device. In case of out-of-sync audio, pausing playback on the casting device may help.

Streams can be cast separately,  although results may vary from stream to stream. For some video files in my tests, something like this worked:

```
mkchromecast --video -i  "/path/to/video"
```

---

For the whole desktop, in Gnome or from Flathub there is 
[GNOME Network Displays](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.NetworkDisplays). (But it didn't work for me in Kubuntu because of errors like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1372783/925128).)